# How to copy an image from App to external storage Unity Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

How can I copy an image from my app to external storage with Unity Android ? I want to store an image in my app, and when the user clicks on a button it appears in the external storage. I found that I can use StreamingAssets or persistentDataPath but it looks like I can only read files from StramingAssets so I can't copy an Image. And I don't understand where my image is supposed to go in persistentDataPath and how it works. I've read the docs and looked on forums but can't find nor understand how to do it. Or is it possible to do it in android studio and then import it as a plugin or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) in case of Android:

> Application.persistentDataPath points to /storage/emulated/0/Android/data//files on most devices (some older phones might point to location on SD card if present), the path is resolved using android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDir.

You can change the Write Permission in PlayerSettings to External (SDCard) to enable write permission to external storage:

[image]

> How can I copy an image from my app to external storage...?

The short answer is: using System.IO. There are many tutorials on this topic, it depends what you want to do. Here is one [example](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1567543/using-encodetopng-to-save-an-image-to-disk.html):

> `Sprite itemBGSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>( "_Defaults/Item Images/_Background" );
>    Texture2D itemBGTex = itemBGSprite.texture;
>    byte[] itemBGBytes = itemBGTex.EncodeToPNG();
>    File.WriteAllBytes( formattedCampaignPath + "/Item Images/Background.png" , itemBGBytes );`